# How to add client_IP to the response header in Kong apigateway

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I'm trying to add "client_ip" in to a response header, but I can see the IP address is being printed on the kong apigateway logs but cannot forward it to a response header,

Sample log output:

```
,"method":"GET"},"client_ip":"49.36.22.209","tries":[{"balancer
```

I was trying following methods to try it out, but still response header is not printed the ip address.

```
- name: response-transformer
  route: routeName
  config:
    add:
      headers:
      - X-Real-IP:${{client_ip}}
```

Can anyone help me to try enable this header on kong apigateway configs ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the plugin "[serverless-functions](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/serverless-functions/#main)"

In your case you would use the "**post-function**" running on service response at "**header-phase**".

With this plugin and post-function you can write custom logic with lua and modify the response.
With pre-function you could modify the request.
Kong have a [PDK](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/pdk/#main) you can use globally.

Either if lb or not you would use
[kong.client.get_ip()](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/pdk/kong.client/#kongclientget_ip) or [kong.client.get_forwarded_ip()](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/pdk/kong.client/#kongclientget_forwarded_ip)

**Example Code**

```
local client = kong.client
local response = kong.response

local function set_client_ip_header()
  local client_ip = client.get_ip() -- or client.get_forwarded_ip()
  response.set_header("X-Real-Ip", client_ip)
end

return set_client_ip_header -- return for memoization
```